# How can I prevent a policy-enforced screen lock in Windows?

Tags: windows, screensaver, security-policy

Our corporate BOFH imposes the screen lock setting with a ridiculously short delay. It's frustrating and counterproductive.

Is there a way to prevent the automatic screen lock? I would assume there is no way to override the policy-enforced setting, but maybe there is a software that mimics user activity.

Just asking before I set up a perpetual mouse wheel. (get it?)

Comment: Just curious what "ridiculously short" is?

Comment: There *are* workarounds like key pressers and mouse movers that will prevent the screen from locking.  But are you sure you want to do this?  Circumventing IT security is more than likely against company policy, and could be a fireable offense.

Comment: 15 minutes. OK, it's not that short ... unless you are at home, not in an open space, and also often working on a second computer. Like I am, so the screen lock is obnoxious.

Comment: One semi workaround is not to block the screensaver, but to set the grace period to a few hours. (That is the time between the starting of the screensaver and the time you need to enter a password. Usually this is set to 5 seconds. So a quick shake with the mouse when the screensaver just kicks in disables it. However with a higher value you can have hours without a password.

Comment: [The grace period](https://superuser.com/questions/329758/how-can-i-prevent-a-policy-enforced-screen-lock-in-windows-7/836346#comment880491_329758) doesn't work for me, while [the script](https://superuser.com/a/836346/137079) does. I assume that my corporate policy also disables the grace period.

Comment: Late to the game here, but wanted to add my solution. Since I don't have admin rights to the PC I use at work, and none of the scripts or programs in this thread worked for me (either they weren't allowed to be installed, or just didn't work), I purchased a "USB Mouse Jiggle" hardware from Amazon. Works like a dream, only $15.

Comment: My previous company has a 2-minute screen lock policy. That's not ridiculous but disaster and torturous and sometimes depressing.

Comment: In the end, I had to use a macro-enabled excel workbook and use macro to move the mouse because everything else was blocked, as given by this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHGI0d0ImNo

Comment: Try mouseJiggle: https://mouse-jiggler.en.uptodown.com/windows

Comment: This is an excellent way to get fired.

Comment: +1 Just for using the term BOFH `:D`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yet another option is freeware [Caffeine](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/) program. It is free for commercial use as well. From the program's homepage:

> If you have problems with your PC locking or going to sleep, caffeine will keep it awake. It works by simulating a key-press once every 59 seconds, so your machine thinks you're still working at the keyboard, so won't lock the screen or activate the screensaver.
>
> Caffeine works by simulating an F15 key up event every 59 seconds. Of all the key presses available, F15 is probably the least intrusive (I've never seen a PC keyboard with that key!), and least likely to interfere with your work.

This off-the-shelf solution also allows you to control when to enable it and disable it:

> Double-clicking the program icon empties the coffee pot, which is what the icon represents, and temporarily disables the program. Double-clicking it again refills the pot, and will keep your machine awake.

Comment: I'm waiting for the day when a Gov't employee puts Caffeine on their computer and it just so happens that something like Shift+F15 launches the nukes...

Comment: Nice easy "off the shelf" solution, thanks.  Seems to have about as many command-line options as gcc, but I don't need to use any of them!

Comment: The tool works great for me!
I had to install the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable to get it working.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368

Comment: I think in a corporate environment you could (and should) get into trouble for installing such a tool on a machine, especially if it's not 'your' machine. The VBS solution is much cleaner, at least you know exactly WHAT it does.

Comment: Please keep in mind that simulating key presses is a quite brutal way to keep your screen from locking. For a better way, please check my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1604470/1182474) out.

Comment: @PolarBear What about Caffeine with the -stes - tell Windows to stay awake, don't use F15

Comment: @Cfomodz, indeed, I see that they have added the `-stes` option recently (v1.95 - February 2021). I haven't tested it. My previous comment was written before this option was introduced. If the option does what it promises then it is the same as the `CoffeeBean` program which I recommended in my previous comment.

Comment: @PolarBear Fair enough. I suppose I didn't even think about that, but I'm glad I didn't make a fool of myself by trying to say you should have suggested it before it existed haha. It does indeed - or at least it has for me - do what it says it does and seems to be the same as 'CoffeeBean' based on your description.

Comment: Microsoft has recently released their version of a similar tool [PowerToys Awake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/awake)

Answer (score 136):

If Windows Media Player is still installed, you can play a video on loop and minimize it (the sample "Wildlife" videos work fine for this).  By default, as long as a video is playing, the screen won't lock.

Comment: Thank you! This is the simplest, most effective solution. 
(I didn't try it though, I left the company a while ago and try to stay away from Windows.)

Comment: I confirm that this works on Windows XP using an MP3 file instead of a video.

Comment: Brilliant hack!

Comment: This also works using VLC for those who prefer it over Windows Media Player

Comment: Great hack. I built a small blank video and batch scripts to start this.  Files at [box.net](https://app.box.com/s/khcc45viol53oswmzo3v) and a blog post at [my personal site](http://www.ericcloninger.com/?p=578)

Comment: @EricCloninger this doesn't play on W2k3 SP2 Media Player; good idea though

Comment: @kubanczyk I had some problems with WMP on Windows 7 to launch into looping mode from a script, but I could launch the video and then manually choose the looping button on the control bar.

Comment: Works fine in Windows 7. Nice hack!

Comment: If you're using VLC, this will only work if the video window is not minimized (but it can be in the background).

Comment: This works on Windows 7 playing an MP3 in minimized Media Player instead of video.

Comment: Does it works on win 10 ?

Comment: @ShatayuDarbhe yes, it works with Windows 10 as well.

Comment: For those who don't have "Wildlife" or any videos on your computer, you could probably find some free-to-use ones from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Featured_videos/en), most companies I know will allow you to access Wikipedia and thereby Commons. But unfortunately, this method does not work for me.

Comment: Any ideas to make this as light on system resources as possible? (e.g. which file, from Wikimedia Commons or Windows system sounds or other, would be "best" suited)

Comment: Playing some small *.midi file in Windows Media Player uses some ~ 35MB RAM (in Win10) vs. < 1MB for Caffeine...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it works without the need to install any additional applications. 

The Caffeine answer seems like it works, but some companies track the apps you install on your computer. And apps that occasionally perform keystrokes could potentially have unintended consequences.

Comment: Would playing songs on spotify have the same effect?

Answer (score 128):

I use a script I title idle.vbs:

```
Dim objResult

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    

Do While True
  objResult = objShell.sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}")
  Wscript.Sleep (6000)
Loop
```

Every six seconds, this quickly toggles numlock on the keyboard, causing Windows to believe that someone is interacting with the keyboard, preventing screen lock. This runs on vanilla windows, you don't need development or scripting tools to use it, just make a text file with .vbs as the extension and double-click it (or place it in your startup items).

Edit: you can put this script in your startup items with

```
 choco install IdleVbs -source https://www.myget.org/F/joshrivers-utility/
```

For more information on the Choclatey (`choco`) CLI installer please see:

https://chocolatey.org/

Comment: @JoshRivers a way to stop this script, without having to restart the computer, would be nice as well.

Comment: @DeeJayh I think you can just find the instance of wscript.exe in Task Manager and kill it. There usually aren't a lot of instances of that executable running. You could probably make an automated solution for termination (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22325745) or by putting code in the Do While section that watches for an external fact. Like have the script create a file on startup, then check that the file exists in While. That way you could just delete the file to make the script terminate. (I never quit the thing, though, so I just run the script and very rarely kill it with Task Manager).

Comment: On Windows 10, an easy way to locate the startup folder is display the Start->Run window (e.g. WindowsKey+R) and then type `shell:startup`.  See this site for more info http://www.thewindowsclub.com/startup-folder-in-windows-8

Comment: To find the script look for Microsoft Windows Based Script Host in your task manager. Or add a column Process Name and then look for wscript.exe.

Comment: Works great on a Win10 Surface laptop - that does not even have a physical NumLock key!

Comment: This seems to work great UNLESS Outlook (365) is the active window and then it doesn't seem to prevent screen lock.  Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: confirming that this doesn't work for me either - probably the policy at hand in my case checks for mouse pointer movement.. i wish we could do this too using VBS but it seems to not be possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019106/how-to-move-the-mouse-using-vbscript

Answer (score 13):

A lot of these answers are old, and only keep alive through inputs/mouse movement. Compile this in C or C++, this will keep the session alive by setting thread execution state (Windows Only ofcourse)

```
#include <windows.h>

//https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate

#define ES_CONTINUOUS       0x80000000
#define ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED 0x00000002
#define ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED  0x00000001

int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        result = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS);
        Sleep(30 * 1000);
    }

    //unreachable
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I don't use Windows anymore these days but this seems useful.

Comment: I guess it is `int main()`

Comment: A PowerShell equivalent implementation is in https://superuser.com/a/1596783.

Comment: Why does the `SetThreadExecutionState` need to be repeated every 30 seconds if `ES_CONTINUOUS` is included?

Answer (score 11):

## 1. (Best option) Microsoft PowerToys Awake

[PowerToys Awake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/awake)
[image]

#### How it works under the hood

The tool uses the [SetThreadExecutionState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) WinApi function to keep the screen on. It is the function that video players use to keep the screen on while you are watching a film.

## 2. CoffeeBean

I have created a tiny tray icon application [CoffeeBean](https://github.com/PolarGoose/CoffeeBean) similar to the PowerToys Awake. The advantages of my tool are:

- Lightweight.
- Supports older versions of Windows.
- Can be used without installation as a standalone executable.

## 3. Autohotkey script

If you know the AutoHotkey tool, you can use the following [script](https://superuser.com/a/1557323/1182474).

Comment: The key thing here is SetThreadExecutionState - thank you! It's then a moments work to create an app/script/whatever and use Task Scheduler to run it every 10 minutes.

Comment: @RhysJones, I'm not sure running it once per 10 minutes is going to work well. You don't need to run it periodically. You just need to run it once and keep the process alive. As long as the thread which called `SetThreadExecutionState` function is alive, OS is not going to lock the screen. That is the idea behind my tray icon application and the Autohotkey script.

Comment: You are right - as Hexagon has also noted, the docs are not very precise.

Answer (score 9):

Extending on [Cherona](https://superuser.com/users/639973/cherona)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1530942/9721), here is an implementation in PowerShell, using SetThreadExecutionState().

As long the script is running, screen saver and screen lock wouldn't start.

```
Set-StrictMode -version 3.0

# Definition of SetThreadExecutionState from -
#   http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetThreadExecutionState.html
#   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate
# "EXECUTION_STATE" changed to "uint", added "public" modifier.
$Signature = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);
'@

$ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040L
$ES_CONTINUOUS        = 0x80000000L
$ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED  = 0x00000002L
$ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED   = 0x00000001L

# Details on Add-Type in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7.
$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Kernel32' -PassThru

echo "Forcing system to not go to sleep (disable screen saver)."
echo "Close the window to allow sleep again."
$result = $Kernel32::SetThreadExecutionState($ES_CONTINUOUS -bor $ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED -bor $ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED)

# Loop until script is forcibly stopped.
While ($true) {
  Start-Sleep (60 * 60 * 24)  # 24 hours.
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I was under the impression that you need to keep calling SetThreadExecutionState every so often, to reset the "system idle timer" described here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate

Comment: @Cherona Yes, I verified that this works for many hours (with the lock screen timeout being set to 1 minute). The documentation is indeed vague, but ES_CONTINUOUS could be interpreted as taking care of that.

Answer (score 8):

You can create an [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script to either continually press an unused key (e.g. make it toggle the num lock, scroll lock), sleep for a minute or so, and repeat.  Alternatively, if you use the keyboard a lot, you could make it move the mouse by a pixel or so in any direction.

If you don't want it continually running, you could also launch the script as a scheduled task (if you have access) to launch after the computer has been inactive for some time.

And this is a very simple script to perform an invisible mouse move, if you don't want to get into AutoIt syntax:

```
While True
   Local $pos = MouseGetPos()
   MouseMove($pos[0]-1, $pos[1]-1, 0)
   MouseMove($pos[0], $pos[1], 0)
   Sleep(540000)
WEnd
```

This script moves mouse cursor by one pixel in the up-left direction and after that returns it back, then sleeps for 9 minutes (`540000` milliseconds). When script is running, you can see AutoIt icon in the tray. You can stop it right-clicking this icon and choosing the corresponding option.

To make a script, install AutoIt, right-click in any folder and choose `New` > `AutoIt v3 Script`, name it, right-click this new script, choose `Edit`, paste the code provided above and save. You can even compile it to `.exe` (again, from context menu) to start, for example, from Windows Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll check it out, seems simpler than a mouse wheel cage setup :)

Comment: Precompiled version of this AutoIt Script here https://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/readynosleepexe-prevents-screensaver-and-pc-locking

Answer (score 8):

I like to use **easy** and **integrated** options (**no additional software**), like a powershell script (thanks https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/prevent-desktop-lock-or-screensaver-with-powershell/) that uses the "f15" as the key to success (thx to caffeine. It's indeed least interfering)

```
param($minutes = 180)

write "... screen will be awake for $minutes"

 $myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"

 for ($i = 0; $i -lt $minutes; $i++) {
 write "... screen will be awake for" ($minutes-$i)
 Start-Sleep -Seconds 60    
 $myshell.sendkeys("{F15}")
}
```

Put this into a myScriptName.ps1 and start it via desktop shortcut or commandline:
`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nop "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\myScriptName.ps1"`

**UPDATE:**
Maybe there was some change from the administrator, but this doesn't work for me anymore 
Now I have to use an autohotkey-script from NBirnel: https://github.com/nbirnel/nosleep - this work **perfect**, because it moves the mouse (without distracting any work)

Comment: I run the code but getting the following error. Please advise

`c:\Powershell>powershell -nop myScriptName.ps1
myScriptName.ps1 : The term 'myScriptName.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ myScriptName.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (myScriptName.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


c:\Powershell>`

Comment: @Sabrina maybe you have to define the full path to your script, so not just "myScriptName.ps1" but "c:\path\to\myScriptName.ps1"

Comment: Can be done as an one-liner shortcut:

    `powershell.exe -Command $s = New-Object -com \"Wscript.Shell\"; while(1){write \".\"; $s.sendkeys(\"{F15}\"); Start-Sleep -Seconds 60;}`

This helps against the policy forbidding PowerShell to execute files.

Can be started "minimised" at once.

Answer (score 6):

There is an android app called "Timeout Blocker" that vibrates at an interval and you can put your mouse on it. It says not to use it at work though. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.isomerprogramming.application.timeoutblocker&hl=en

Comment: question is asking about Windows..

Answer (score 5):

Compile this in Visual Studio or C# Express and run it from a command prompt (or double click it). Requires .NET 4.0 or above. It does everything you are looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace ImWorkin
{
    class Program
    {
        [FlagsAttribute]
        public enum EXECUTION_STATE : uint
        {
            ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001,
            ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
            ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000
        }
        public SYSTEMTIMEOUTS TimeOuts
        {
            get { return sysTimeouts; }
        }
        public struct SYSTEMTIMEOUTS
        {
            public int BATTERYIDLETIMEOUT;
            public int EXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT;
            public int WAKEUPIDLETIMEOUT;
        }

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE flags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint ="SystemParametersInfo")]
        internal static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, ref int pvParam, int fWinIni);

        private static System.Threading.Timer preventSleepTimer = null;
        public const int SPI_GETBATTERYIDLETIMEOUT = 252;
        public const int SPI_GETEXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT = 254;
        public const int SPI_GETWAKEUPIDLETIMEOUT = 256;
        public static int Counter = 0;
        public static int timeOutinMS = 0;
        public static int batteryIdleTimer;
        public static int externalIdleTimer;
        public static int wakeupIdleTimer;
        public static SYSTEMTIMEOUTS sysTimeouts;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are about to be workin!! Just a moment...I need to calculate a few values.");
            string dots = string.Empty;
            for (int i =2; i < 60; i++)
            {
                dots = "";
                for (int ii = 0; ii < i; ii++)
                {
                    dots = dots + ".";
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("You are about to be workin!! Just a moment...I need to calculate a few values.");
                Console.WriteLine(dots);
            }


            GetSystemTimeOuts();


            if (timeOutinMS < sysTimeouts.BATTERYIDLETIMEOUT)
                timeOutinMS = sysTimeouts.BATTERYIDLETIMEOUT;
            if (timeOutinMS < sysTimeouts.EXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT)
                timeOutinMS = sysTimeouts.EXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT;
            if (timeOutinMS < sysTimeouts.WAKEUPIDLETIMEOUT)
                timeOutinMS = sysTimeouts.WAKEUPIDLETIMEOUT;

            if (timeOutinMS == 0)
                timeOutinMS = 30;

            DisableDeviceSleep();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("OK. I have calculated your computers timeout periods and set the   ");
            Console.WriteLine("necessary hooks. Your computer will not shut off the monitor, will");
            Console.WriteLine("show active in any chat programs,the screensaver is disabled and ");
            Console.WriteLine("the computer will not lock! Anyone looking at you eaither locally ");
            Console.WriteLine("or remotely will think you are hard at work.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Now go do something fun...I got your back ;)");
            Console.WriteLine("Oh yeah....if you close this window OR press `q' in this ");
            Console.WriteLine("window you are going to have to actually work.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("This text will disappear in a 30 seconds. Just in case someone comes ");
            Console.WriteLine("by and reads your screen!");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Need custom coding? Kenneth.gore@gmail.com");
            while (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true);

                if (cki.KeyChar == 'q')
                    break;
            }

        }


        public static void DisableDeviceSleep()
        {
           SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS);
           preventSleepTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(PokeDeviceToKeepAwake), null, 0, timeOutinMS * 1000);
        }

        public static void EnableDeviceSleep()
        {

           preventSleepTimer.Dispose();
           preventSleepTimer = null;

        }

        private static void PokeDeviceToKeepAwake(object extra)
        {

            Counter++;
            try
            {
                   SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS);
                   IntPtr Handle = FindWindow("SysListView32", "FolderView");

                   if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                   {
                       SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
                       SendKeys.SendWait("%1");
                   }

                   if (Counter > 1)
                       Console.Clear();
            } 
            catch 
            {

            }
        }

        public static void GetSystemTimeOuts()  
        {
            sysTimeouts.BATTERYIDLETIMEOUT = -2;
            sysTimeouts.EXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT = -2;
            sysTimeouts.WAKEUPIDLETIMEOUT = -2;


            if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETBATTERYIDLETIMEOUT, 0, ref batteryIdleTimer, 0) == 1)
                sysTimeouts.BATTERYIDLETIMEOUT = batteryIdleTimer;
            else
                sysTimeouts.BATTERYIDLETIMEOUT = -1;

            if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETEXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT, 0, ref externalIdleTimer, 0) == 1)
                sysTimeouts.EXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT = externalIdleTimer;
            else
                sysTimeouts.EXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT = -1;



            if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWAKEUPIDLETIMEOUT, 0, ref wakeupIdleTimer, 0) == 1)
                sysTimeouts.WAKEUPIDLETIMEOUT = wakeupIdleTimer;
            else
                sysTimeouts.WAKEUPIDLETIMEOUT = -1;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry....in the above post everything after the phrase "Looking for." is code and should be compiled. It didn't format correctly. The code demonstrates some pretty cool pInvoke for those interested. Btw....after compiled, I just put it in my path somewhere like c:\windows. This way if I'm at a cmd prompt I can type ImWorkin and I'm good to go :)

Comment: You can modify your answer by clicking the **edit** link below it.

Comment: please edit your first answer and then delete this one.

Comment: WTF is up with the "Just a moment, I'm calculating a few values!" dummy loop?

Comment: In response to the c# code posted its usually customary to give credit to the author. That happens to be me. I posted this almost two yeas ago on stack Overflow I believe.

Comment: It seems that `SPI_GETBATTERYIDLETIMEOUT`, `SPI_GETEXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT` and `SPI_GETWAKEUPIDLETIMEOUT` are only [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms942638(v=msdn.10)) as working with Windows CE.

Answer (score 5):

Mouse Jiggler might be an option:
https://mousejiggler.codeplex.com/

Comment: This works just great :)

Answer (score 4):

*This is a solution which works for **Win10** and with MS Office (that is, PowerPoint) installed:*

MS **PowerPoint** (if MS Office is installed). Hit **<kbd>F5</kbd>** to start "presentation mode". Now move to a different "desktop" (so that the "presentation" doesn't interfere with your actual work) by pressing <kbd>Windows-logo</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and you're good to go :)

---

<sub>PS: it *might* also work for **Win7** without multiple "desktops", e.g. with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.</sub>

Comment: Seems to have stopped working...

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Mouse Move](https://github.com/sw3103/movemouse) this for ages now.
Advantage over Caffeine, options are customisable via GUI.

The Windows 10 version seems new, needs to be installed from Windows Store. Recommend the older one since is portable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case just this one line did the trick:

```
SendKeys.Send("{CAPSLOCK}{CAPSLOCK}");
```

Just put it in the `Timer_Tick` event and set timer interval to e.g. 60000ms.

Comment: ok, it's quite late to resume this answer but consider sending not one but two CAPSLOCK if you don't want me to staRT YELLING IN THE MIDDLE OF A STACKOVerflow comment without understanding why (it tooks a couple of minutes to write this comment)

Comment: @GianPaolo you're right. This is what I did. I thought it's clear but maybe I should modify the answer.

Comment: And 6 years after answering it’s still a single capslock invoke... smh

Comment: Great if this answer could be put into context... e.g. save it as a script, execute in cmd, ... ? - on second thought, other answers provide the context, e.g. https://superuser.com/a/836346/183485

Answer (score 1):

I love @JoshRivers 's solution of VB script.
And I updated a little bit to stop it with duration time.

```
Dim objResult
Dim intervalSec
Dim durationSec
Dim cnt

intervalSec = 60
durationSec = 3600

cnt = 0

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    

Do While True
  objResult = objShell.sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}")
  Wscript.Sleep (intervalSec*1000)
  cnt = cnt + 1
  If durationSec <= (intervalSec * cnt) Then
      Exit Do
  End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else are writing scripts to fake being at the keyboard.

The correct way to handle it is to:

- go into the registry where the policy is
- set the value to whatever you want
- and alter the registry key permissions
- only **Deny** write access to anyone except yourself

This lets you block the policy from taking effect on your PC. But be aware that you need to have Administrator access to the registry.

Comment: When the admins disable the screen lock settings, editing the registry is already disabled.

Comment: @GabrielR. As an administrator you can alter the ACL on the registry keys. If i get the patience i'll link the talk from Mark Russinovish where he mentions getting rid of the Microsoft group policy that locked down his own laptop. If you're an administrator you have full control of the machine. It likely has to start with taking ownership of the registry keys, then granting yourself full control, then denying anyone else anything except read access.

Comment: I have administrative access and can regedit. How can I find where the policy is set in the registry? I also couldn't find it in gpedit in the usual places.

Comment: @IanBoyd I actually am getting a special logon via lsass.exe from the system user in my event logs under security just before I'm timed out. Is this really a group policy / registry thing?

Answer (score 0):

**Mouse Jiggler** was the right option for me*

the mouse does not actually move using the zen switch.

a working download link (2022/01):
https://mouse-jiggler.fr.uptodown.com/windows

one file, 984Ko, no registry key.

Unzip, run. Use the swithes below from a console or a shortcut to autorun :

```
MouseJiggler.exe -j -m -z -s 50
```

this will start MouseJiggler activated (j), minimized (m), with no visible moves (j), triggered every 50 secs.

sources, MouseJiggler switches, chocolatey installation :
https://github.com/arkane-systems/mousejiggler

(*)
thanks @kkr for your [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/329758/how-can-i-prevent-a-policy-enforced-screen-lock-in-windows/1211878#1211878). Cafeine was not working for me using the `-stes` arg (I use putty a lot)

Answer (score -5):

You should disable the "screen lock"/"sleep mode" from control panel > power options > change plan settings.
Her in click the drop down for "Put the computer to sleep" and select "never".

Comment: Domain admins can have a policy-enforced screen lock in Windows.