# Logon screen win7

Tags: windows-7, login

I have a small problem with windows logon. Since I used Asrock A-Tuning USB-key logon, when I log out (lock screen) windows shows me this screen:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Before I used USB-key logon, windows used to show me that screen:

[image: Screenshot 2]

and I would like to know how to delete the first screen. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please upload to something other than dropbox, so we can inline the screenshots, you can just upload the images then post the urls for us.

Comment: @M's let us know if your this link solve your problem http://superuser.com/questions/395708/windows-7-disable-lock-workstation-after-10-minutes-using-group-policy , it is, your por turn into possible duplicate.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia thank you very much, it helped! Now I can only lock my pc with winkey+R (can't do it through start->lock), but it doesn't matter to me. Thank you!