# Writing a Simple AutoHotkey Script (press a key every X second on desktop)

Tags: autohotkey

I need to press any useless key (like F11) every 5 minutes or less to keep the windows active (if it became inactive for 5 minutes it will lock-out).

But I need the key to be pressed on the desktop (so it doesn't effect any open windows).

I have tried

```
Loop
{
   ControlSend, {F11}, WindowsApplication1
   Sleep, 100000
}
```

but doesn't seem to work.

thanks.

Comment: Is this to keep a remote desktop session open?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to send <kbd>F11</kbd> to the desktop?
If it's just to keep your computer awake you can use the following script:

```
#SingleInstance, force
#Persistent
SetTimer, NoSleep, 30000
Return

NoSleep:
 DllCall( "SetThreadExecutionState", UInt,0x80000003 )
Return
```

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208(VS.85).aspx):

> **SetThreadExecutionState function**
>   Enables an application to inform the system that it is in use, thereby preventing the system from entering sleep or turning off the display while the application is running.

---

It is also possible to emulate mouse-action to keep the system from sleeping
(if above script somehow doesn't work for you):

```
Loop {
    Sleep, 30000
    MouseMove, 1, 0, 1, R  ;Move the mouse one pixel to the right
    MouseMove, -1, 0, 1, R ;Move the mouse back one pixel
}
```

So there would be no need to emulate actually *pressing a key*.

Comment: @Unorthodox Didn't this answer work for you?

Comment: The autohotkey script can be simplified, look at [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1557323)

Answer (score 0):

In previous comment, @Rik proposed an AutoHotkey script. It works, but let me provide a simpler version:

```
#Persistent ; script will stay running after the auto-execute section (top part of the script) completes
#SingleInstance Force ; Replaces the old instance of this script automatically

; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate
; 0x80000002 = ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED
DllCall("SetThreadExecutionState", UInt, 0x80000002)
```

This script will make Windows think that there is an application running which shouldn't be interrupted by the screensaver (but you can still lock your screen manually by pressing a default Win+L key combination, for instance). It is the technique which is used by media players in order to prevent your screen from switching off while you are watching a video. This technique works even if there are corporate policies enforced which don't allow you to disable screen locking in Windows options.