# Cannot find the reason lock screen still pops up after inactivity (Win 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, asus-laptop, lock-screen

I'm running Windows 10 Home (build 19044.2006) on Asus UX481FL and the lock screen always pops up after inactivity timeout.

```
Screen Saver Settings > "On resume, display logon screen" is off
Sleep is "Never"
Hibernate is "Never"
System unattended sleep timeout is 999999min (for some reason it doesn't switch to "Never")
Sign-in options > "Allow Windows to automatically lock your device when you're away" is off
```

What else do I have to check?

**UPD:** "Interactive Logon: Machine Inactivity Limit" set to 0, still have the issue.

Comment: You want to change the group policy setting called "Interactive Logon: Machine Inactivity Limit" However, i don't think you'll be able to change group policy using Win10 Home. You need pro. You might find there is a powershell command out there to directly change the setting though. You can cheat your way out of Home limitations if you know the precise command for what you want.

Comment: You also have this option: https://superuser.com/questions/329758/how-can-i-prevent-a-policy-enforced-screen-lock-in-windows

Comment: @Mastaxx As for the program, it's not what I'm looking for. By simulating activity it denies turning the screen off as well.

Comment: Yeah so your best bet is finding a way to get into the interactive logon setting i mentioned. Are you able to access the group policy menu? If you can't find it in the start menu you can try running it from the run menu by typing: gpedit.msc

Comment: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/automatically-lock-computer-after-inactivity-in-windows-11.4774/

Comment: @Mastaxx I'm getting an error while executing "gpedit.msc": "Windows cannot find gpedit.msc".

Comment: Because you're running Windows 10 Home edition and gpedit is only available in Pro. You can manually enable it yourself though. Download this bat file and run it as administrator. Then reboot your computer and try again. https://www.itechtics.com/?dl_id=43

Comment: Original source: https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/

Comment: @Mastaxx I used this lines to enable policy editor: FOR %F IN ("%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~*.mum") DO (DISM /Online /NoRestart /Add-Package:"%F")
FOR %F IN ("%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~*.mum") DO (DISM /Online /NoRestart /Add-Package:"%F") Now I can change these settings, so I set "Interactive Logon: Machine Inactivity Limit" to 0. Let's see, if this would work.

Comment: good stuff! be great to know.